# Difference between Rule and Pattern

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolfram-language

Please, explain me the main difference between the Rule and the Pattern in the following examples:

[image]

Why we are got the different results for `->` and `:>`?

Another one thing I want to reproduce is what should I do to obtain from expression `5+4` the result `41` via transform `5+4` to `5^2+4^2` so that to use something like:

```
(5 + 4) /. (x_ + y_) -> (x^2 + y^2)
```

or

```
(5 + 4) /. (x_ + y_) :> (x^2 + y^2)
```

instead of

```
{5, 4} /. {x_, y_} :> x^2 + y^2
```

Comment: Try `Trace[x=4;y=2;expr={5,5};expr/.{x_,y_}:>x^2+y^2]` Then try `Trace[x=4;y=2;expr={5,5};expr/.{x_,y_}->x^2+y^2]` Carefully compare the output of those two. The output of `Trace` for each `{code,result}` is showing what the code is and what the result of running that code is.  As the docs say: `lhs:>rhs` represents a rule that transforms lhs to rhs, evaluating rhs only after the rule is used. And `lhs->rhs` represents a rule that transforms lhs to rhs. And the rhs is evaluated the moment it reads `lhs->rhs` After studying this example can you see what is happening now?

Comment: There's a dedicated site for Mathematica: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/